# Explicit formula for $n$th prime in terms of Riemann zeros:

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

We all know there exists an explicit Formula for prime counting function in terms of Riemann zeros.

I'm wondering if similar formula exists for $n$th prime in terms of Riemann zeros?

Or any other conjectured explicit  formula for nth prime? ( Probably analytic).

I'm looking for analytic function for nth prime.

Comment: Could you define exactly what you mean by a formula for the nth prime?